# How do I correctly reference an image in nuxt project?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, assets

I'm creating a modal in the app.html file of my Nuxt project that tells IE users that they should change to a different browser with links to 3 browsers they can download. The modal is displaying but no matter how I try and reference the images I get a 404 not found error. I have the 3 .png images in assets/images.

I tried referencing them in different ways (including **`~/assets/images/imagename.png`**) but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you look here? 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

Answer (score 0):

Please have look at [original Nuxt documents](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/) once.

with img tag

```
<img
   src="~/assets/images/about-us.png"
>
```

Comment: This is how I used it in the app.html file but still getting that error: <a
   href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/"
   target="_blank"
>
   <img src="~/assets/images/firefox.png"/>
   <p>Firefox</p>
 </a>

Comment: <img :src="require('@/assets/images/firefox.png')" /> can you try this!